# Unable to send mail from controller to queue

Tags: laravel

I have a question;
I have a controller in laravel which now sends the mail with

Mail :: to ($ Str2) -> send (new Sendmail ($ value));

Where $ str2 comes from a query.

Then I have a Mailable which via
build () does the following:

return $ this-> markdown ('emails.mailbulk')

(and some other stuff fills)

Now this leads to a 'too many emails per second' error. That's why I want to use qeue.

When i change in the controller Mail :: to ($ Str2) -> queue (new Sendmail ($ value)); then i see the job in the table. But after queue:work no mail is being send....

How can my controller now put the mail in the queu?
-> do I have to create a separate class in ShouldQueue, or can this be shorter?

Comment: Are you using an email service like Mailchimp or do you have your own mailserver?

Comment: at the moment i am using mailtrap for testing, 
At mailtrap i recive 2 mails. and laravel shows me the error of too many mails per second.

Comment: Mailtrap allows you to send only 3 mails per second, are you trying to send more?

Edit: and could you also tell a little bit more about the application, when is this email sent. is this something that happens after a button press or in a cronjob?

Comment: This part of the application is for an cronjob.This part of the application is for an cronjob.
the controller does:
1. looks in the table if a person is connected to an record.
2. foreach person connected to a record look for the email =$Str2
3. get the array of all linked todo-records 
4. Mail :: to ($ Str2) -> send (new Sendmail ($ value));

Comment: if i say in the controller Mail :: to ($ Str2) -> queue (new Sendmail ($ value)); then i see the job in the table. But after queue:work no mail is being send....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think moving this into a queue will not solve your problem. You need a way to limit the amount of emails you send to Mailtrap.

Just wait a second after each mail. If nothing else in your application and you don't have a lot to send email this is good enough.

```
$emailsToSend = emailsToSend();

foreach ($emailsToSend as $emailToSend) {
    Mail::to($email)->send(new Sendmail($value));
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: This does the job for now.. need to send out max 50 mails.

Comment: Could you kindly accept this as answer if it solves your problem? :)